# How do I set a function to run every screen update in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a function that runs every screen update in javascript a while (true) loop freezes the entire screen:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="label">Something should display</p>
    <script>
      var l = document.getElementById("label");
      while (true){
        l.innerHTML = "Something";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So is there a way to kind of do this???

Comment: There's no `update` event, what's supposed to trigger the function?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "on screen update"?  Are you looking for [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)?  Something else?

Comment: Do you mean literally a `while (true) { ... } ` loop? If so, where is it in your example?

Comment: Are you trying to run something periodically, as in, every 10ms? Or are you trying to run something like an animation and tie it to the screen's redraw loop?

Comment: @meagar every few ms

Comment: Then you don't want `requestAnimationFrame`. You want `setInterval`.

Comment: @meager Ok thanks, also I do not wan't my account banned from asking questions I got a warning about it from downvotes this is my second question to.

Comment: I'm newer to posting on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a function run on the next frame with `window.requestAnimationFrame(callback)`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="label">Loading</p>
  <script>
    var l = document.getElementById("label");

    function update() {
      l.innerHTML = Date.now();
      window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    update();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```